# Кеширование стилей

Tags: wordpress, кэширование

Есть проблема с кешированием сайта, возможно кто кто уже имел дело с этим.

Есть сайт на WP. Когда внес изменения в css - эти изменения не видно. Когда нажимаеш ctrl+f5 - все хорошо, изменения работают. И когда снова обновить страницу - все по старому - без изменений.

Кеширование на хостинге и на сайте отключено. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Всё верно - статика кешируется браузером.

Comment: Я думаю проблема в самом браузере, попробуй открыть в режиме инкогнито и посмотреть.

Comment: В инкогнито гуд. Но проблема что это только с одним сайтом. Остальные работает нормально

Answer (score 0, accepted):

это браузерное кеширование. Способы отключения:
1 - добавить мета-параметр в head

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
```

2 - добавить следующий код в htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
</IfModule>

# Заголовок Expires
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive On ExpiresDefault "now"
</IfModule>
```

Для разработки можно выключить в dev tools во вкладке network на уровне браузера